# Stencil painting on another texture

Tags: texture-painting

I would like to clarify something:

I have a plane that is subdivided and "split" into two. Both sides have been assigned exactly the same texture material with the only difference being that "Texture.003" is a copy of "Texture.02". Now, I want to stencil paint road marking only on one side of the plane, however, as you can see, it paints it on both sides. Does that mean that I need to create a copy of the texture itself outside of Blender and then use that texture to be able to paint on only one side?

If there is a better way of achieving the same result I would appreciate your input. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things here, the texture and the plane topology.

If you want to paint on a texture you either need to duplicate this texture (if you want to keep an unchanged version) or create a brand new image texture with transparent background that will come over the texture through a *Color > MixRGB* node for example.

If you don't want to paint on the other side of the plane you need to either give thickness to the plane so that you'll paint on another face that has a different material (but you still need to use one of the previously cited solutions), or in your material use the *Backfacing* output of an *Input > Geometry* node as factor in *MixRGB* node. It will allow you to display 2 different images on the 2 opposite sides of the plane.